# How can I implement a buffer for decrypt and play the video?

Tags: java, android, encryption, video-streaming, caesar-cipher

I need to create an implementation that decrypt video files. I'm currently using the AesBase64 algorithm to decrypt these videos, but in my tests decryption became too heavy for Android because the byte array and released completely in memory, with so I'm getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError when the fileIt has more than 25 MB. My question is: How can I implement a buffer for me to decrypt each byte array and already play the video for each decrypted byte?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "AesBase64" but it sounds like a mish-mash of AES encryption and Base64 encoding. You can implement a streaming decryptor by using the update methods of the [Cipher](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) class. Unfortunately the android [Base64](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) class does not really support piecemeal base64 decoding, though you could implement it yourself without too much effort. However, a much simpler alternative exists: use [CipherInputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/CipherInputStream.html) and [Base64InputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64InputStream.html).

Use something like the following:

```
public void decrypt(String filename) throws Exception {
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("filename"));
    Base64InputStream base64Stream = new Base64InputStream(bis, 0);
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(base64Stream, c);
    byte[] plainBuf = new byte[2048];
    int nRead;
    while ((nRead = cis.read(plainBuf)) > 0) {
        // send plainBuf[0] through plainBuf[nRead-1] to the video codec
    }
    cis.close();
}
```

Comment: I think this type of implementation can solve my problem. Do you have any examples of how to create a video codec? Right now I'm only sending the file path to my class and videos starting with android.media.MediaPlayer.

Comment: No, I don't know anything about android video.